# getStaticPaths() returns 404 Page Not Found

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, next.js

The `getStaticPaths()` keeps throwing the 404 page and I'm guessing that is because of the function `getAllPostIds()` which is meant to return an array of objects. I'm making use of typescript, I've declared the array of objects but I'm not sure how to use the replace method on the `id`

```
interface ArrObj {
    params: {
        id: string;
    }
}
let arrObj: ArrObj[];

export function getAllPostIds() {
    const fileNames = fs.readdirSync(postsDirectory);

    return fileNames.map(fileName => {
        return {
            params: {
                id: fileName.replace(/\.md$/, '')
            }
        }
    })
}

export function getPostData(id) {
  const fullPath = path.join(postsDirectory, `${id}.md`)
  const fileContents = fs.readFileSync(fullPath, 'utf8')

  const matterResult = matter(fileContents)

  return {
    id,
    ...matterResult.data
  }
}
export async function getStaticPaths(){
    const paths = getAllPostIds();
    return{
        paths,
        fallback: false
    }
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const postData = getPostData(params.id)
  return {
    props: {
      postData
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `getAllPostIds` and `getStaticPaths` functions look fine. Do you get any errors logged on the server? Could you show us the `getStaticProps` function too?

Comment: I've added it to the code.....

Answer (score 1):

Add the `fallback` props as `true` or `blocking`. Seting it as false will return a 404 page because the requested path was not generated during build time.

```
return{
   paths,
   fallback: true
}
```